# Can't print String in console

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am getting this error when I try to print

> Error  C3867   'Carta::mostrar': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

**Carta.h**

```
using namespace System;
    ref class Carta
    {
    private:
         String^ cara;
         String^ palo;

    public:
         Carta();
         Carta(String^ pCara, String^ pPalo);
         String^ mostrar();
    };
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Carta.h"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
int main(array<String^>^ args) {

    Carta^ nueva = gcnew Carta("1", "Diamantes");
    Console::WriteLine(nueva->mostrar); //Error here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console::WriteLine(nueva->mostrar); //Error here
```

You are trying to access a member of `nueva` object instead to call a method of this object. `mostrar` is a method, not a property. Try to change to:

```
Console::WriteLine(nueva->mostrar());
```